# How to unit test while holding a variable with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

My controller function has:

```
$scope.openForgotPasswordModal = function() {
  var forgotPasswordModal;
  forgotPasswordModal = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: '/templates/passwordReset.html',
    scope: $scope,
    size: 'lg'
  });
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    return forgotPasswordModal.close();
  };
};
```

Testing the opening of the modal is easy enough:

```
it('should open a modal', function() {
  $scope.init();
  $scope.openForgotPasswordModal();
  expect($modal.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    templateUrl: '/templates/passwordReset.html',
    scope: $scope,
    size: 'lg'
  });
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    forgotPasswordModal.close();
  };
});
```

How can I test the `closeModal` function?

Comment: I kown you're asking about unit tests but if you're also doing e2e testing, I find it much easier for modals

Comment: Hmmm - sadly, no `e2e` setup yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that this is a unit test and $modal is an external dependency, the proper way to test it would be to mock $modal:

```
var $modalMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('$modal', ['open']),
    forgotPasswordModalMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('$forgotPasswordModal', ['close']);
$modalMock.and.callFake(function(){
    return forgotPasswordModalMock;
});

beforeEach(angular.mock.module(function($provide){
    $provide.value('$modal', $modalMock);
}));

it('should open a modal', function() {
    $scope.init();
    $scope.openForgotPasswordModal();
    expect($modalMock.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        templateUrl: '/templates/passwordReset.html',
        scope: $scope,
        size: 'lg'
    });
});
it('should close a modal', function(){
    $scope.closeModal();
    expect(forgotPasswordModalMock.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

If $modal is broken, this test should still pass, since the inner workings of $modal are outside the scope of this particular unit test.

Answer (score 2):

I use the spyOn function to return a fake object when calling $modal.open():

```
var fakeModal, myController;
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $modal) {
    fakeModal = {
        result: {
            then: function (confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
                //Store the callbacks for later use to mimic the click of the button.
                this.confirmCallBack = confirmCallback;
                this.cancelCallback = cancelCallback;
            }
        },
        close: function (result) {
            this.result.confirmCallBack(result);
        }
    };

    spyOn($modal, 'open').and.returnValue(fakeModal);

    myController = $controller('MyController', {
        $modal: $modal,
    });
 }));
```

Then, it's possible to spy fakeModal.close() and know if it was called:

```
spyOn(fakeModal, 'close').and.callThrough();
$scope.closeModal();
expect(fakeModal.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
```